# My php page simply isn't taking POST data from my C# script

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, post

I have no issue creating working SQL and PHP code. I have no issue creating C# code that works internally.

My single issue is that I cannot manage to get my C# script (from within Unity, btw) to pass a string to ascended.us/monstro/login

That's it! Are there any brilliant minds here who can help me get past this one obnoxious hurdle?

Many thanks!

I tried to get the below code to send the form to my page. Yes, Unity *is* sending the web request, but it isn't transferring the post data over. Below is the C# side of things.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

public class MyBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Upload());
    }

    IEnumerator Upload()
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://www.ascended.us/monstro/login.php", "{ \"loginUser\": 1, \"field2\": 2 }", "application/json"))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my PHP script to accept the C# UnityWebRequest

```
<?
        $sqllink = mysqli_connect("localhost", "REDACTED", "REDACTED", "REDACTED"); //THESE ARE VERIFIED TO BE CORRECT
    if (!$sqllink)
    {die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ' - ' . mysqli_connect_error());}
        
        $loginUser = $_POST["loginUser"];
        
        $query = "INSERT INTO inbound_data (data) VALUES('$loginUser')";
        mysqli_query($sqllink, $query);
?>
```

I understand that this script isn't secure, so consider it a hello world application. What ends up happening when I run the script is that it inserts a value into my SQL table, but the value is empty, signifying that the post variable wasn't transferred. Can you please help?

Perhaps I need permissions of some sort? I am using BlueHost if that helps. There simply **has** to be an easy way to get this post data to actually get sent to my PHP page from C#! I have tried the other tutorials and similar responses on this site (and many others) but they aren't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# script looks fine for sending POST request, but it seems the data format might be wrong for the PHP script to receive. In your UnityWebRequest you're sending JSON data, but your PHP script is trying to access `$_POST["loginUser"]`, which is used for regular form data, not JSON data.

You can modify your C# script to send the data as form data with the following:

```cs
IEnumerator Upload()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("loginUser", "1");
    form.AddField("field2", "2");

    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://www.ascended.us/monstro/login.php", form))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        }
    }
}
```

In your PHP script, you can access the data using `$_POST`:

```php
<?php
$sqllink = mysqli_connect("localhost", "REDACTED", "REDACTED", "REDACTED");
if (!$sqllink) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ' - ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$loginUser = $_POST["loginUser"];

$query = "INSERT INTO inbound_data (data) VALUES('$loginUser')";
mysqli_query($sqllink, $query);
?>
```

With the modified code you're sending the POST data as form data from Unity, and your PHP script is accessing the POST variables correctly using `$_POST["loginUser"]`.

Let me know if you continue to face issues.

Comment: This is exactly what fixed it! You're a wizard! Thanks Joaquin!!! Now my project can finally connect to my database! This code in combination with your fix could potentially help a lot of people... Note: There are a LOT of other confused people + bad tutorials online on how to get this connection to work.